# Weighted mean over different rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with three variables like this one:

```
variable <- c("A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C")
mean <- c(2,4,5,4,3,1,5)
counts <- c(100, 200, 300, 150, 400, 200,250)

df <- data.frame(variable, mean, counts)
```

I want to multiply the `mean` with the number of `counts` and add them per `variable`. Then I want to divide the result by the number of `counts` per `variable`. The result should look like this example for the `variable A`:

(2 * 100 + 1 * 200)/300 = 1.333333

Then I want to aggregate the result per `variable` like in the `group_by` and `summarise` function in `dplyr`. Any Idea how this works? I tried it with group_by and `mutate` but there was no aggregation. The result should look like this one:

```
Variable     Mean
A         some value
B         some value
C         some value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work - you just have to specify the calculation because a call to `mean` will of course divide by the count (e.g. 2 for the first one) 
    library(tidyverse)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(multiple = mean * counts) %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarise(mean = sum(multiple) / sum(counts))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(.data = df,.variables = c('variable'),
    function(x){sum(x$mean*x$counts)/sum(x$counts)})
```